# Android kotlin type inheritance failed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

*INTRODUCTION:*

I created an android project following this example: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/

I had to add a class that holds the response status(Success/Error) and it's value, **in the repository** it looks basically like this:

```
sealed class Result<out R> {
  data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
  data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

It is meant to be better than classic:

```
class Result<T> (
  val success: Boolean,
  val data: T?,
  val exception: Exception?
)
```

Because :
- In this case the Success result definitely has only `data` and the Error only `exception`.
- As both Success and Error Message are inheriting from Result, due to [Kotlin Smart Casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html), the validation looks simpler:

```
var responce: Result<DataEntity> = dataSource.GetData()
if (responce is Success) {
    doSomethingWith(responce.data)
} else if (responce is Error) {
    throw responce.exception
}
```

*PROBLEM:*

All good, but when i'm trying to asynchronously observe data from a local dataSource (using Room lib):

```
interface TaskDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
    fun observeTasks(): LiveData<List<TaskEntity>>
}

class SqlLocalDataSource(
    private val taskDao: TaskDao,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
): LocalDataSource {

    override suspend fun observeTasks(): LiveData<Result<List<TaskEntity>>> = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
            taskDao.observeTasks().map {
            Success(it)
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me the following Error: `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is LiveData<Result.Success<List<TaskEntity>>> but LiveData<Result<List<TaskEntity>>> was expected`

Which is strange because Success inherits from Result

*I TRYED:*

- I make sure that the types are correct (Result ids not from some other library)
- To make the function run on the main thread, but its impossible to call DB from the main thread

Comment: Show me your import inside SqlLocalDataSource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It gives me the following Error: `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is LiveData<Result.Success<List<TaskEntity>>> but LiveData<Result<List<TaskEntity>>> was expected`
>
> Which is strange because Success inherits from Result

But `LiveData<Success<...>>` does *not* inherit from `LiveData<Result<...>>`. Please read about [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) and take into account that `LiveData` is declared in Java and so can't be covariant.

I don't know why type inference would fail with `suspend` and work without it, but the problem can be fixed by being more explicit about types:

```
taskDao.observeTasks().map {
    Success(it) as Result<List<TaskEntity>>
}
```

Or better, to avoid a cast:

```
fun <T> success(x: T): Result<T> = Success(x)

taskDao.observeTasks().map {
    success(it)
}
```

Comment: `Success(it) as Result<List<TaskEntity>>` would defeat the purpose as i wouldn't be able to verify like this the response: `if (responce is Success)`, isn't it?

Comment: No, you would. The cast doesn't actually change the value.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that its not permitted to Use LiveData in a suspend function, after I changed the function to a non suspended the error disappeared :

```
 override fun observeTasks(): LiveData<Result<List<TaskEntity>>> {
    return taskDao.observeTasks().map {
        Success(it)
    }
}
```

May be somebody can explain why is it?